# angular reference to HTML document property

Tags: html, angular, typescript, casting

I am looking for accessing to document HTML via HTML object.

By searching in net found I could add

```
providers: [{ provide: "windowObject", useValue: window}]
```

in app.module

and then inside my app I could inject the window object as the following :

```
constructor(@Inject("windowObject") private window: Document) {
   console.log(window);
}
```

My problem is that when I want to access to the document via

```
console.log(window.document);
```

I get error in type script as "Property 'document' does not exist on type 'Document'."

So it looks I need to cast it somehow and I tried HTMLDocument for casting but still I get the same error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the window type in your constructor parameters as

```
private window: Window
```

Reference: [Window | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)